# Echoing matched data from 2 arrays with php

Tags: php

I am trying to compare the contents of 2 arrays

```
   <?php
      $badwords = array('badword1','badword2','badword3');
      $domains = array('domainword1.com', 'word2domain.com', 'domain.com');
      if (preg_match($badwords,$domains) { // searched and did not find if it works like this
        - echo the $domains that matches the $badwords // this is what i don't know how to do
      }
```

It should echo in this case:

Matched domains are:

`domainword1.com`

`word2domain.com`

in new rows.

How am i suppose to do this?

Comment: @Deepu Yep forgot the quotes on domain.com

Comment: Did you even read the documentation for `preg_match` before writing this code? It doesn't accept arrays as arguments.

Comment: @Jon, I noticed there were some variable inside a preg_match, but not quite like this. Don't know exactly how to do it. This is a bit like more thinking code.

Comment: Feeding just arbitrary “words” to `preg_match` will not succeed … you should look up what the “preg” part of the function name actually stands for.

Comment: What counts as a match in this case?

Comment: @Jim If there is data from first variable `$badwords` that matches in any of the data of the second variable `$domains` then it should echo only the domains that contains the data from the second variable (matched data).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really don't know why you need regex in this case. Secondly, as [`Jim`](https://stackoverflow.com/users/505722/jim) mentioned `What counts as a match in this case?` Well that's the thing.

You need to rewrite your **`$badwords`** array from

```
$badwords = array('badword1','badword2','badword3');
```

to

```
$badwords = array('word1','word2','word3');
```

Using the below code you get the desired output.

```
<?php
$badwords = array('word1','word2','word3');
$domains = array('domainword1.com', 'word2domain.com', 'domain.com');
$newarr = array();    
foreach($badwords as $k=>$v)
{
foreach($domains as $k1=>$v1)
{
if(strpos($v1,$v)!==false)
{
array_push($newarr,$v1);
}
}
}

print_r($newarr);
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => domainword1.com
    [1] => word2domain.com
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't use preg_match like this if you need to match any of $badwords to any of $domains.
Instead you should do something like this:

```
<?php

$badwords = array('badword1', 'badword2', 'badword3', 'badword(\d+)');
$domains = array('domainword1.com', 'word2domain.com', 'domain.com', 'badword1.com', 'ohbadword123.com');

$badDomains = array_filter($domains, function($domain) use ($badwords) {
    $found = false;
    foreach ($badwords as $badword) {
        // use this if you dont' need regular expressions:
        // if (substr_count($domain, $badword)>0) {
        // use this if you need them:
        if (preg_match('/' . $badword . '/', $domain)) {
            $found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return $found; 
});

if (!empty($badDomains)) {
    echo "Domains with bad words:\n - " . join("\n - ", $badDomains);
}
```

Comment: I get an error http://codepad.org/oLIgFfFZ `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION on line 5`

Comment: @Adrian What is your version of PHP? You can look it up in command line (php -v) or with this script: <?php phpinfo(); ?>

Comment: 5.2.17, read about this, may be causing problems. if you have a version lower than 5.3. Any way thanks.